# Spring WebFlux Controller Mapping Issues -Double Wildcard

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, request-mapping

I'm in a Spring WebFlux context and i'm trying to use the double wildcard mapping feature.

As the documentation says (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)

Double wildcard should match any path segment. With this mapping value `/**/c-{someId}` 
I expect to match all of this:

- `/c-123456`
- `/foo/c-123456`
- `/foo/bar/c-123456`

Actually, it's matching one and only one path segment -> `/foo/c-123456`

Is there any solution ? Or should I report a issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected, since `**` is meant to match `zero or more path segments until the end of the path` (see [`PathPattern` Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html)). So `/**/c-{someId}` is an illegal pattern here.

You can open an issue or even better, contribute an improvement on the reference documentation.

I'm not aware of any way to match all requests with a pattern like that unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I understand the fact that it is an illegal pattern since `**` match `zero or more path segments until the end of the path`. But, it actually works fine in a Spring MVC context. Do you know why ?

Comment: It works in Spring MVC because it's not using the same path matching algorithm. Spring MVC is using `PathMatcher` and Spring WebFlux is using `PathPattern` (a different, optimized implementation that's behaving differently)